# Multiple device token targets to a single Android device in AWS SNS

Tags: java, android, cordova, amazon-web-services, sencha-touch

I'm facing an issue in AWS SNS GCM, below is the scenario:

- When app installed in mobile and after lunching an application it register with GCM and receive a token and send to the server
- Now uninstalling the app and installing again, it received new token from GCM, and sending back to server
- Now when server sending notification on both tokens old and new one, mobile receiving two notifications

It means previous token still working for that mobile.

This issue is only happening with Android, not in iOS

How it should be stopped? Any solution

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`gcm.register("project number");` to create a new token

`gcn.unregister();` to unregister the previous token;

above code is deprecated so use

```
InstanceID.deleteToken() or InstanceID.deleteInstanceID().
```

Comment: When it should be performed? because I'm removing the app, after that my local storage is clear

Comment: whenever you get a new token for that particular user you have to unregister the token from backend

Comment: I'm using AWS SNS, and sencha app have AWS cordova plugin which is register with GCM and after receiving token its sending to my back server for storage

Comment: is there any login functionality in your app ?

Comment: Yes there is login functionality in app

Comment: whenever you do login at same time you have to read your previous token in backend and do gcm.unregister(); for that token and save a new token in aws, so that it will delete the previous token from GCM SERVER.

Comment: Totally agree with you, but in other case what happen if user login on multiple devices with same login credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to write the token to

- (Android) a profile
- (iOS) the keychain

When you start the app you need to check for the token. If there is already a token available (but nothing within your database [e.g. localStorage, sqlLight]) you need to unregister the token.